# React router differentiate between two parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `"react-router": "^5.1.2",` and there is a component called CarJourney for which i have created a path like

> path: '/seguro-carro/simulacao/:journeyId?/:userId?',

so as you can see journeyId and userId are optional parameters defined here but i came accros a scenario where i have to get these parameters and hit a different api with these

So, for example if my route contains

> /seguro-carro/simulacao/ba6e7ae5-adb6-4722-87df-4f414c575bbb/abcdef

i can use useParams query like

```
const params = useParams()
console.log(params) to get both these parameters which gives journeyId='ba6e7ae5-adb6-4722-87df-4f414c575bbb' and userId="abcdef"
```

but if my route contains only userId and not journeyId like

```
/seguro-carro/simulacao/abcdef
console.log(params) gives me journeyId="abcdef and userId=undefined
```

Is there any way i could fix this issue ? In this case journeyId should be undefined and userId should abcdef.

Thanks !

Comment: you can give /seguro-carro/simulacao/undefined/abcdef

Comment: @BuildThough dont want user to see undefined in the url :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can likely provide two paths for matching. List the more specific path first. If a path with two params is used then the more specific path is used and both parameters are assigned, and if a path with only the one is used, the less specific path assigning the parameter to `userId` is used. Don't use optional parameters.

Example:

```
<Route
  path={[
    '/seguro-carro/simulacao/:journeyId/:userId',
    '/seguro-carro/simulacao/:userId'
  ]}
  ... other props
/>
```